# What's the difference between finding the average Euclidean distance and using inertia_ in KMeans in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I've found two different approaches online when using the Elbow Method to determine the optimal number of clusters for K-Means.

One approach is to use the following code:

```
distortions_2.append(sum(np.min(cdist(data
                              , kmeanModel.cluster_centers_
                              , 'euclidean')
                              , axis = 1)) / data.shape[0])
```

Another is to use inertia_ from sklearn.cluster.KMeans:

```
distortions_3.append(kmeanModel.inertia_)
```

When I plot the results (using the same random states) both give different results but I'm not sure what the differences are, can anyone help?

Comment: you can post this question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) and get some help

Comment: @seralouk do not suggest people to post duplicates! If it is better suited for CV, it should be migrated and not duplicated!

Comment: this will need to be merged with https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/31989/whats-the-difference-between-finding-the-average-euclidean-distance-and-using-i

Comment: This has already been answered here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between finding the average Euclidean distance and using inertia\_ in KMeans in sklearn?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/31989/whats-the-difference-between-finding-the-average-euclidean-distance-and-using-i)

Answer (score 1):

K-means does not minimize Euclidean distances, but *squared* Euclidean distances. This is not the same.

The nearest center is the same for both, but the *mean* only optimizes the squares. You can find the counterexample on my earlier answers here.

The proper value to use for the basic elbow approach is the "inertia", which is the sum of squares. But some evaluation measures may use other distances. For example the Silhouette index *can* be used with other distances.

Don't forget that these approaches are just heuristics for trying some k. Always also consider other values.